# How to implement the add/edit links on a field in the admin change page that does not have an expressed FK relationship in the model?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a Django 3.x web site. There are 3 models, among others, `Document`, `MetaData`, `MetaDataValue`. The `MetaDataValue` model has a foreign key relationship to the `MetaData` model.

In a simple world, there would be a foreign key relationship from `MetaData` to `Document`. Then the `DocumentAdmin` would display the `MetaData` field as a dropdown, filled with the appropriate `MetaDataValues`. There would also be edit/add (pencil/plus) links next to the dropdown to allow the user to edit/add the `MetaDataValue` for that `MetaData` object.

However, one of the requirements for the project was not to define which, or how many, `MetaData` objects would be associated with a particular `Document` type until run time. Those associations are through another set of models. Therefore, the `Document` admin change page adds the different `MetaData` fields to the change admin page at run time, by looking into the database for which `MetaData` fields are associated with this type of `Document`, and then adding them to the fieldset through the `get_fieldsets` method.

The implication of this design is that one cannot edit/add values to a particular `MetaData` field on the `Document` admin change page, because, I assume, Django lost the underlying foreign key relationship between the `Document` and `MetaData` models because the fieldset is generated in the admin's `get_fieldsets` method.

I could add pages of code to show how the `MetaData` fields are generated at run time, but I don't think that would make the description any clearer. I have looked at the page source and fieldsets generated for the "simple world" example described above above, and cannot see where Django is figuring out when to add the edit/change links to the drop down for a particular foreign key field.

My question, is how can I add the pencil and plus sign to these `MetaData` fields displayed in the `Document` admin change page, and give the user to option to add/edit the `MetaDataValue` for that particular `MetaData` object? I could just create some Ajax calls and do all the heavy lifting myself, bu I would prefer to leverage as much of the Django infrastructure as possible, and not reinvent more than I have to.

Thanks!

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using the `RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper`. I added this widget wrapper to all my selects that needed the green plus (add) and yellow pencil (edit).

There is too much code to post here, but here is the meat of it. My db table `MetaData` has the names of all the fields, and `MetaDataValue` has the values for each metadata field. The metadata is used to describe a document (text, video, image), but there are no FK relationships between the `MetaData` model and the `Document` model. The relationship between the metadata and the documents is contained in a JSON field in another table. The `MetaData` table also has what type of Django field is used for that metadata field. There is also another table that determines which metadata fields apply to which document type (image, text, video). For all the `ModelChoiceFields`, I add the field and the widget (`Select` wrapped in a `RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper`).

```
elif (metadata_names[i].field_type == MetaData.MODELCHOICEFIELD):
            fields[metadata_names[i].name] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=MetaDataValue.objects.filter(metadata_id=metadata_names[i].metadata_id).order_by('value'), required=False, label=metadata_names[i].label, help_text=metadata_names[i].help_text)
            # add the green plus (add) and pencil (edit) links to each select field
            fields[metadata_names[i].name].widget = RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper(fields[metadata_names[i].name].widget, MetaDataValue._meta.get_field('tag_value'), admin_site, can_add_related=True, can_change_related=True)  
            if 'documentType_id' in fields:
                # Editing/add a new document type seems like a bad idea, as document type is used a lot in the processing logic
                fields['documentType_id'].widget.can_add_related = False
                fields['documentType_id'].widget.can_change_related = False
```

The hard part was getting the right arguments for the `RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper`. The documentation is a little sparse on that widget, because, I think, it was an early part of the admin, but much of the Django code has changed since it was first implemented, so a lot of ways this wrapper was used in the past (ie stack overflow posts) has been deprecated. I just looked at the source, and tried what seemed to be appropriate until it worked.  Finally, these articles helped a lot:

- [RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper](http://dashdrum.com/blog/2012/07/relatedfieldwidgetwrapper/)
- [More RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper – My Very Own Popup](http://dashdrum.com/blog/2012/12/more-relatedfieldwidgetwrapper-the-popup/)
- [How can I remove the add and change buttons from a TabularInline admin field?](https://newbedev.com/how-can-i-remove-the-add-and-change-buttons-from-a-tabularinline-admin-field)